# error: use of undeclared identifier 'makeDest'

Tags: c++, uci

This project is supposed to take in user input of coordinates of multiple locations and then compare distance and state how far they are.

I am having issues with them communicating with each other.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bigfunction.hpp"
#include "coord.hpp"
#include "dest.hpp"
int main()
{
    distloop();
    return 0;
}
```

#### bigfunction.cpp

```
#include "bigfunction.hpp"
#include "coord.hpp"
#include "dest.hpp"

double convertRadians(double deg)
{
    double pi,radians;
    pi = 3.1459265;
    radians = pi * (deg/180.0);

    return radians;
}

void distloop(void)
{
    Dest start,far,closest;
    std::string shortest, currentloc, farthest;

    int counter;
    double distance, max, min;

    max = 0;
    min = 0;
    std::getline(std::cin,currentloc);
    makeDest(start,currentloc);
    std::cin >> counter;
    std::cin.ignore(1);

    for (int i=0; i < counter;i++) {
        std::getline(std::cin,currentloc);
        distance = findDist(start,currentloc);

        if (min==0) {
            min = distance;
            shortest = currentloc;
        }

        if (distance > max) {
            max = distance;
            farthest = currentloc;
        }

        if (distance < min) {
            min = distance;
            shortest = currentloc;
        }
    }

    makeDest(far, farthest);
    makeDest(closest,shortest);
    std::cout<<"Start Loc"<< strDest(start) <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Closest Loc"<< strDest(closest) << " (" << min << "miles)" << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Farthest Loc"<< strDest(far) << " (" << max << "miles)" << std::endl;

}
```

#### bigfunction.hpp

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

#ifndef BIGFUNCTION_HPP
#define BIGFUNCTION_HPP
#include "dest.hpp"
#include "coord.hpp"
double convertRadians(double deg);
void distloop(void);
#endif
```

#### dest.cpp

```
#include "dest.hpp"
#include "bigfunction.hpp"
#include "coord.hpp"
double findDist(Dest &dest, std::string location)
{
    double RAD = 3959.9;
    double dlat,dlong,a,c,dist;
    double lat2 = getLatitude(getField(location,1));
    double long2 = getLongitude(getField(location,2));

    dlat = dest.lat - lat2;
    dlong = dest.longt - long2;
    a = ((sin(convertRadians(dlat/2.0)))*(sin(convertRadians(dlat/2.0)))) + (cos(convertRadians(dest.lat))*cos(convertRadians(lat2)) * sin(convertRadians(dlong/2.0)))*(sin(convertRadians(dlong/2.0)));
    c = 2 *atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a));
    dist = RAD * c;

    return dist;
}

std::string strDest(Dest &dest)
{
    std::string prtStr;
    prtStr = dest.latstring + " " + dest.longstring + " ("+ dest.name + ")";
    return prtStr;
}

void parseCoor(Dest &dest)
{
    dest.lat = getLatitude(dest.latstring);
    dest.longstring = getLongitude(dest.longstring);
}
```

#### dest.hpp

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

#ifndef DEST_HPP
#define DEST_HPP

struct Dest
{
    double lat, longt;
    std::string latstring,longstring, name;
};

void parseCoord(Dest &dest);
//void makeDest(Dest &dest, std::string location);
double findDist(Dest &dest, std::string location);
std::string strDest(Dest &dest);
#endif
```

#### coord.cpp

```
#include "bigfunction.hpp"
#include "coord.hpp"
#include "dest.hpp"
std::string getField(std::string location, int field)
{
    int m = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int e = -1;
    std::string info;

    for (int i = 0; i < location.length(); i++) {
        if (location[i] == ' ') {
            m++;
            s = e + 1;
            e = i;
        }

        if (m == field) {
            if (field > 2) {
                info = location.substr(s, location.length());
                return info;

            } else {
                info = location.substr(s, e - s);
                return info;
            }

        } else {
            return info;
        }
    }

    return info;
}

double getLatitude(std::string latit)
{
    char d = latit.at(latit.length()-1);
    double latt;

    if(d == 'S') {
        latt = -1 * std::stod(latit.substr(0,latit.length()-2));

    }  else {
        latt = std::stod(latit.substr(0,latit.length()-2));
    }

    return latt;
}

double getLongitude(std::string longit)
{
    double longt;
    char d = longit.at(longit.length()-1);

    if(d == 'E') {
        longt = std::stod(longit.substr(0,longit.length()-2));
    } else {
       longt = -1 * std::stod(longit.substr(0,longit.length()-2));
    }

    return longt;
}
```

#### coord.hpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#ifndef COORD_HPP
#define COORD_HPP

std::string getField(std::string location,int field);
double getLongitude(std::string longit);
double getLatitude(std::string latit);
#endif
```

Comment: In `dest.hpp` you've commented out the line where it is declared and you've never made the function itself.

Comment: Improved formatting